# Probability generating function of a distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, generating-functions

> I have to prove that the function
>   $$ \rho(s)=\frac{2}{(2-s)(3-s)}, \ 0\leq s\leq 1$$
>   is a probability generating function of a distribution. Calculate this distribution and its mean, variance, and standard deviation.

I try first use partial fraction, obtaing that
$$ \rho(s)=\frac{2}{(2-s)(3-s)} =\frac{2}{(s-3)(s-2)} =\frac{A}{(2-s)}+\frac{B}{(3-s)} $$
with some calculations I obtained that $A=2$ and $B=-2$ then $$ \rho(s)=\frac{2}{(2-s)(3-s)} = \frac{2}{(s-3)}-\frac{2}{(s-2)} $$

but How can I applied the definition of Probability generating function of a distribution ?

Someone can help me to solve this pls. Thanks for your time and help everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the geometric series:

$$\frac{1}{s-2} = -\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{s}{2}} = - \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{s}{2} \right)^k.$$

Derive a similar expression for $\frac{1}{s-3}$. Plugging this into your computations allows you to determine the probability mass function (and, thus, the distribution).

Comment: Yea, I did it. Thanks. Just a question the distribution can be calculated finding the $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \rho(s) ds$ ?

Comment: @Knight No, I don't think so. Why would you expect this?

Comment: Can you give tell me how can I compute the distribution I tried but I can't.

Comment: @Knight What did you try....?